Snowflake Pandas Error: AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'
I'm trying to read data from a Snowflake table using Python (pandas). When I execute the following code:
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
url = URL(
    user="MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT",
    password="MY_SECRET",
    account="my_account",
    warehouse="MY_WAREHOUSE",
    database="MY_DATABASE",
    schema="MY_SCHEMA",
    )

engine = create_engine(url)
connection = engine.connect()

df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from my_table', connection)

I get an error:
AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'
I set up my virtual environment with:
$ pip install --upgrade snowflake-sqlalchemy
$ pip install pandas


Managed to get it working by using:
$ pip install -U "pandas<2.2"

This solution worked!
